# How to return 2 function calls in the arrow function at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Is there way to return 2 items in the same return of the arrow function?

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () =>
            removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll) and setName('');
    }, []);
```

Please don't offer using useEffect twice

Comment: No need to set state in unmount. It won't be reflected anywhere if you think of i

Comment: Since none of the answers includes an explanation: If you want to include multiple statements (e.g. two function calls) in an arrow function then you declare with a body: `() => { ... statements here ... }`, pretty much like a normal function expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your code to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
            setName('');
        }
    }, []);
```

But setting `state` on `unMount` is not suggested

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Can you check please this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022888/how-to-overcome-the-state-overwriting-in-the-bellow-sample-in-react

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
useEffect(() => {
   return () => {
     removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
     setName('');
 }           
}, []);
```